# Ajax i want to get this echo Line from php file . keeps getting me error

Tags: php, jquery

how can i grab this line from php file with ajax to replace the current html of a div

```
<div style = "width:260px;height:400px;max-height:400px;overflow:auto;">
  <textarea name = "message" onkeydown="send(event, '<?php echo $trow['id'];?>');" id = "text<?php echo $trow['id'];?>" style = "max-height:60px;width:240px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;resize:none;"></textarea>
  <table class = "table">
    <?php 
       while($erow = mysql_fetch_array($erun)){
       $fromid = $erow['fromid'];
       $us = mysql_query("select * from user where id = $fromid");
       $fus = mysql_fetch_array($us);
       ?>
    <tr><td>
        <div id = "change<?php echo $trow['0'];?>">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img src = "profpic/<?php echo $fus['14'];?>" class="media-object" style = "margin-right:5px" height = "40px" width = "40px">
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h6 class="media-heading"><b><?php echo $fus['title']?> <?php echo $fus['fname']?> <?php echo $fus['lname']?></b></h6>
            <font size = "2"> <?php echo $erow['content']?>
          </div>
    </td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$("#divid").load("/path/to/script.php");
```

Comment: `script.php` is the script you posted. You put my answer in the Javascript that wants to replace the DIV with the HTML from that script.

Comment: thanks for replying again but i still dont get it what do i use

($div).load("script.php") does not work having error 
($div).replaceWith("script.php") string value how can i call script

Comment: It's `$("div")`, not `($div)` -- that's basic jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the idea of your question, you need to output JSON data, right? Then you have to use the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method that PHP offers, like this:

The prototype:

```
string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] );
```

The code you should have:

```
$information = " <div style ='width:260px;height:400px;max-height:400px;overflow:auto;'>
    <textarea name = 'message' onkeydown='send(event,'<?php echo $trow['id'];?>');' id ='text<?php echo $trow['id'];?>' style = 'max-height:60px;width:240px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;resize:none;'></textarea>
    <table class = 'table'>
    <?php 
    while($erow = mysql_fetch_array($erun)){
    $fromid = $erow['fromid'];
    $us = mysql_query('select * from user where id = $fromid');
    $fus = mysql_fetch_array($us);
    ?>
    <tr><td>
    <div id = 'change<?php echo $trow['0'];?>'>
    <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
    <img src = 'profpic/<?php echo $fus['14'];?>' class='media-object' style = 'margin-right:5px' height = '40px' width = '40px'>
    </a>
    <div class='media-body'>
    <h6 class='media-heading'><b><?php echo $fus['title']?> <?php echo $fus['fname']?> <?php echo $fus['lname']?></b></h6>
    <font size = '2'> <?php echo $erow['content']?>
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div> ";

echo json_encode( $information );
```

Comment: `<?php` code is not executed inside a string. This will just put the raw PHP code in the AJAX result.

Comment: You haven;t mentioned that you want to replace the content of a DIV.